How to solve the problem that two h files in vscode need to call each other
two .h file is call each other, and causes compilation to fail
in stack_tree.h, i need to use TreeNode*,but it is defined in tree.h, so i try to include "tree.h",just like the following code:
stack_tree.h:
#include "tree.h"
#define variable_type TreeNode*
#define MaxSize 50

typedef struct stack
{
    variable_type data[MaxSize];
    int top;
}SqStack;   

but in tree.h , i need to use SqStack, so i have to include "stack_tree.h",This causes the two h files to include each other，then compile is false
tree.h:
typedef struct tree
{
    int val;
    struct tree *lnext;
    struct tree *rnext;
    SqStack* next;
}TreeNode;

how can i solve this problem?
now, i try to add forward declaration like struct stack
tree.h
//#include "stack_tree.h"
struct stack;

typedef struct tree
{
    int val;
    struct tree *lnext;
    struct tree *rnext;
    struct stack *next;
}TreeNode;

and in stack_tree.h
#include "tree.h"
#define variable_type TreeNode*
#define MaxSize 50


typedef struct stack
{
    variable_type data[MaxSize];
    int top;
}SqStack;   

in my main.c
#include "stack_tree.h"
#include "tree.h"

int main(void)
{
    SqStack* test = (SqStack*)malloc(sizeof(SqStack));
    test->data[0]->val = 1;
    printf("%d\n",test->data[0]->val);
    return 0;
}

it compile successful ,but it can't run , the error is segmentation fault

These types should be in the same header.

You need to use a forward declaration in order to avoid cicular #include dependency.

Because tree.h does not need to know definition of struct stack, you could use something like this:
tree.h:
struct stack;

typedef struct tree
{
    int val;
    struct tree *lnext;
    struct tree *rnext;
    struct stack *next;
}TreeNode;

There is no need to include stack_tree.h in tree.h.
This line is forward declaration:
struct stack;

It is just indicator for compiler that struct struct stack exists.
That allows limited usage of struct stack pointers when compiler does not know definition of struct stack.
You can also typedef SqStack in tree.h if you want to use SqStack in tree.h:
tree.h:
struct stack;
typedef struct stack SqStack;

typedef struct tree
{
    int val;
    struct tree *lnext;
    struct tree *rnext;
    SqStack *next;
}TreeNode;

For example standard FILE is declared by this way in stdio.h for hiding FILE definition from library users.

I would probably add something like: "Then tree.h doesn't need to include stack_tree.h"

Also you could add some explanation about the concept of a forward declaration (struct stack;).

Ok, answer updated according to the previous comments.

you are right,compile is successful, but when i run it, it's not work,and the error is segmentation fault

@cooffeeboy - your main() function uses uninitialized pointer: test->data[0]

You need include guards. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard
stack_tree.h:
#ifndef STACKTREE_H
#define STACKTREE_H

#include "tree.h"
#define variable_type TreeNode*
#define MaxSize 50

typedef struct stack
{
    variable_type data[MaxSize];
    int top;
}SqStack;

#endif

tree.h:
#ifndef TREE_H
#define TREE_H

#include "stack_tree.h"

typedef struct tree
{
    int val;
    struct tree *lnext;
    struct tree *rnext;
    SqStack* next;
}TreeNode;

# endif


Have you tested this?

Not this code specifically, but I have plenty of C header files which include each other in various codebases.

Sure. The problem here is SqStack and TreeNode. One will be used before it's defined.

That is correct. I did not notice that. My bad.

You can write struct again in tree.h.
or use #ifndef & #define:
a.h
#ifndef DONT_INCLUDE_B
#include "b.h"
#undef DONT_INCLUDE_B
#endif

// Rest of the code

b.h
#define DONT_INCLUDE_B
#include "a.h"

// Rest of the code

you can do something like that too (I reccomend)
a.h
#ifdef ONLY_STRUCT
#undef ONLY_STRUCT

struct some_struct
{
   int a;
};

#else

#include "b.h"

// Rest of the code

#endif


Never do this - you've now defined what's supposed to be the same thing twice, thus creating an undocumented, untraceable, and most of all unenforceable dependency between two independent source files.  If the definition gets changed in one but not the other the entire code base is broken.
